# Calculating P values in order to test hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Im looking for some clarification. When I look up the Z value of 0.83 on a table, I arrive at a P value =(1-0.7967) = 0.2033. However, when using a P value calculator such as the one on omnicalculator.com, I get an answer of 0.202328. I'm assuming this second answer is more correct, but is there anyway to arrive at this answer without using software? The course I am in only gives access to Z tables.

Comment: Probably not, this depends on how accurate and detailed the table is. Have you tried interpolating between two neighboring values of 0.83?

Comment: Theoretically a calculator version will sometimes be more accurate because there are only set z scores across a given table.

Comment: The second answer is *less* correct because you transcribed it wrong (I checked with that site.)  It should be $0.20\color{red}{32}694\ldots = 0.2033$ to four decimal places, *exactly* agreeing with the value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The tabulated value have a fixed number of decimals or significant digits, so the result is truncated. Clearly a calculator give you more significant figures, but I think it is irrelevant for practical purposes.